# How to get environment variable in shopify public app using react js?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, shopify, shopify-app

I can not get the environment variable by this process in Shopify public app with react js

```
const { SHOPIFY_API_KEY } = process.env;
```

OR

```
const SHOPIFY_API_KEY = process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY;
```

I consoled the SHOPIFY_API_KEY parameter and it gives **undefined** output.